# Product options not displaying on product page

Tags: template, custom-options

I've inherited a Magento site from a client to work on as a complete Magento novice.

One of their requirements is to add in an additional option to one of the products for "installation". I have set this up in the Magento back end:

[image]

The issue occurs now is that the purchase button and option button is now missing from the product page. Only an "add to wishlist" and "add to compare" link. From the template (addto.phtml) is :

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product) ): ?>
    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

I've compared this with the equivalent in 'base' but it doesn't appear to do anything different in there either.

When I remove the option, the order button is reinstated.

How do I get the option and order button to appear?

Thanks

(I have cleared all caches)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really have to check is presence of

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
```

in the `catalog/product/view.phtml` template of you theme. Because this it the place where options are output.

Comment: Thank you. I don't appear to have a container1 but container2 is there and doing the trick nicely!

Comment: It's better to have both as depending on individual product settings options can be rendered in any of these blocks.